# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException with jMeter

Tags: jmeter, httphostconnectexception

I'm getting this `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException` exception in my jMeter script which I'm unable to debug.

- Test server is successfully able to connect to my application urls (https://apac1.onesourcetax.com and https://emea1.onesourcetax.com)
- jMeter script is successfully able to connect to EMEA1 **but unable to connect to APAC1** (`HttpHostConnectException` exception)
- I wanted to compare between what requests jMeter is sending vs what Chrome browser is sending... so I enabled fiddler proxy inside my jMeter script and guess what?? jMeter script is able to connect to APAC1 when sending requests thru Fiddler proxy (localhost:8888)

[image: debug logs]

Does anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: Is there any description message inside HttpHostConnectException?

Comment: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html):

[image]

So my expectation is that it is something environmental.

I would recommend the following troubleshooting steps:

1. It might be the case the [HTTP connect timeout](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout) it too low and if it takes some time to establish the connection from your location to the server in [APAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia-Pacific) region JMeter might close the connection if it doesn't receive anything from the server. You can try increasing the Connect Timeout, the setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))

   [image]
2. You can get extra information on outgoing requests and incoming responses by [enabling debug logging for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/), the level of details as at my first screenshot you can get by adding the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
   <Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="debug" />
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick up the changes.

Comment: Increasing timeout did not help. Debug level logs also not showing any more details. I'm adding the debug logs to my question now.

Comment: I'm still do not what is causing this issue but I have found a workaround. Running jMeter tests thru our datacenter proxy now.